# How to mount the properties file in Kubernetes configmap using manifest yaml

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I use minikube on windows 10 and try to test Kubernetes ConfigMap with both literal type and outer file type. First I make below manifest yaml file to make ConfigMap.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap  
metadata:
  name: simple-config
data:  
  mysql_root_password: password
  mysql_password: password
  mysql_database: test

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: blog-db  
  labels:
    app: blog-mysql  
spec:
  containers:
  - name: blog-mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    env:  
      - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        valueFrom: 
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: simple-config
              key: mysql_root_password
      - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
        valueFrom: 
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: simple-config 
            key: mysql_password
      - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
        valueFrom: 
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: simple-config
            key: mysql_database
    ports:
      - containerPort: 3306
```

The above configmap yaml file throws no errors. It works successfully. This time I try to test kubernetes configmap with file.

**== configmap.properties**

```
mysql_root_password=password
mysql_password=password
mysql_database=test
```

But I am stuck with this part. Most of configmap examples use kubectl command with --from-file option like below,

```
kubectl create configmap simple-config --from-file=configmap.properties
```

But I have no idea how to mount the properties file using manifest yaml file grammer. Any advice?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I divide the configmap data part into outer properties file and want to know how to mount the external properties file into manifest yaml file.

Comment: without using a ConfigMap?

Comment: Where is the thing you are trying to mount?  To where are you trying to mount it?  (You'd typically copy the text of the file into the ConfigMap, and then mount that in a container, if what you were trying to do is replace the environment variable settings in your process with a Java properties file.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not directly mount a properties file in a pod without first creating a ConfigMap from the properties file.You can create configMap from env file as below

```
kubectl create configmap simple-config \
       --from-env-file=configmap.properties
```